# Huge data import from MySQL to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, bigdata, query-performance

I'm looking for a solution to speed up MySQL data but after trying with the indexing I didn't find the solution to speed up the MySQL count(*) data. so I use elasticsearch for better performance. I have around 3 million records in MySQL and I want to import all record with join as well so I use PHP elasticsearch plugin to import the data but it will also take very long time. then I use logstash and create a script for reading data but it also not work. I have run my system whole night then logstash will insert only 600 000 records. so what is the solution for this? do I need to improve MySQL performance to import into elasticsearch or any other way to import large data into elasticsearch.

check my script also.

```
input {
  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.3:3306/repairs_db"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_page_size => 50000 
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT r.id,r.brand_id,r.product_brand,r.product_description,r.store_id,r.product_group,r.product_id,r.itm_product_group_desc,r.first_name,r.last_name,r.status,r.damaged,r.is_extended_warranty,r.is_floor_stock,r.is_inhome,r.callcentre,r.is_bsp_case,r.created,r.updated,r.is_sandbox_mode,pro.itm_descriptor,st.name as store_name,rp.name as repairer_name from requests r JOIN products pro ON r.product_id = pro.id JOIN stores st ON r.store_id = st.id JOIN repairers rp ON r.repairer_id = rp.id"
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "172.17.0.3:9200"
  "index" => "req-migrate"
  "document_type" => "data"
  }
}
```

Please suggest me something to load the data into elasticsearch. Can we use MySQL as well for such a situation?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP?

Comment: Can you execute the SQL query fine & quickly?

Comment: for data limit with offset is working fine. but for pagination like i want total count for all records it will take time.

Comment: Could it be possible that the result of the SQL query is too big for Logstash? Maybe you have to increase the size of the queue between the input and the output. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/persistent-queues.html

Comment: Please provide examples of the `SELECTs` you are trying to optimize.  Also, how many times will such queries be run per load into Elasticsearch?